# Select all cells with a value under header

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that selects the column which has "Address" header.

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Address")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Address column was not found."
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

I want to select 2nd row or the row after the header "Address" all the way down to the last row with value.

Comment: `Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Offset(,1).Select`

Comment: I edited my question, what I mean select the next row after the header "Address". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `Range(rngAddress.offset(1), rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select`

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the difference of that line and this line: `Range(rngAddress.Cells(2, 1), rngAddress.End(xlDown).Cells(2, 1)).Select`

Comment: Not much.  The `.Cells(2,1)` when referring to a single cell does the same as offset(1).  I would not offset after the `End(xlDown)` you are no including  an extra empty cell on the bottom.  As you have it written `Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Offset(1).Select` would give you the same range without extra typing.

Comment: I see. I got it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to locate the column header label in the first row.

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
    dim cl as long
    with worksheets("Sheet1")
        if not iserror(application.match("address", .rows(1), 0)) then
            cl = application.match("address", .rows(1), 0)
            .range(.cells(2, cl), .cells(rows.count, cl).end(xlup)).select
        else
            MsgBox "Address column was not found."
            Exit Sub
        end if
    end with
End Sub
```

I prefer to look from  the bottom up to find the last populated cell in a column but if you prefer to look from the top down, the above code could be easily modified to suit.

The [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx)¹ method is not always the most reliable method of referencing individual or groups of [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)s. Directly referencing the parent worksheet with a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) should help.

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In case you have blanks in your address column, use this code:

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
  Dim rngAddress As Range, LastRow As Long
  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Address")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Address column was not found."
  Else
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, rngAddress.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(2, rngAddress.Column), Cells(LastRow, rngAddress.Column)).Select
  End If
End Sub
```